# How to make a Batch file that loops for N files or a whole folder?

Tags: batch-file

I need to make a windows batch that works in this way:

- you may drag on it **X** file, or
- you may drag on it a folder containing **X** files

The batch will loop for all the files and write a file (in the passed folder or in the folder of the first passed file) containing something like this:

```
file1=FirstFileFound.ext
file2=SecondFileFound.ext
...
file**X**=LastFileFound.ext
```

I've found various examples here about counting and writing files, but i'm not able to manage the variable number or type of arguments.

Is it possible? 
If not, I'll be happy as well with two separate batch files, one for files and one for Folders, but a single file would be the best.
Could someone make an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I want to show you a way of handling multiple file and directory arguments of a batch file (delivered by command line or by drag-and-drop). For every provided directory argument, its content is enumerated; if you set variable `RECURSIVE` to a non-empty value, the directory is processed in a recursive manner:

```dos
@echo off
rem /* Define recursive mode globally: */
set "RECURSIVE="

rem // Loop through all arguments:
for %%A in (%*) do (
    rem // Call sub-routine for each argument:
    if not "%%~A"=="" call :RESOLVE "%%~fA"
)
pause
exit /B

:RESOLVE
rem // Check if item is file or directory:
set "ATTR=%~a1"
if not "%ATTR:~,1%"=="d" (
    rem // Process a single file:
    call :PROCESS "%~1"
) else (
    rem // Check for recursive mode:
    if not defined RECURSIVE (
        rem // Process all files in a directory:
        for %%B in ("%~1\*.*") do (
            call :PROCESS "%%~B"
        )
    ) else (
        rem // Process all files in a directory recursively:
        for /R "%~1" %%B in ("*.*") do (
            call :PROCESS "%%~B"
        )
    )
)
exit /B

:PROCESS
rem // Process a single file (simply echo it):
echo %~1
exit /B
```

---

To apply this for your task, you could use the following script:

```dos
@echo off
rem /* Define recursive mode globally: */
set "RECURSIVE=" & rem // (empty means off, so non-recursive)
rem /* Define list file name: */
set "LISTFILE=%~n0.lst" & rem // (use batch script name + `.lst`)

rem // Determine target location, depending on first argument:
set "ATTR=%~a1"
if defined ATTR (
    if "%ATTR:~,1%"=="d" (
        set "LOCATION=%~f1\%LISTFILE%"
    ) else (
        set "LOCATION=%~dp1%LISTFILE%"
    )
)

set /A "COUNTER=0"
rem // Loop through all arguments:
for %%A in (%*) do (
    rem // Call sub-routine for each argument:
    if not "%%~A"=="" call :RESOLVE "%%~fA"
)
exit /B

:RESOLVE
rem // Check if item is file or directory:
set "ATTR=%~a1"
if not "%ATTR:~,1%"=="d" (
    rem // Process a single file:
    call :PROCESS "%~1"
) else (
    rem // Check for recursive mode:
    if not defined RECURSIVE (
        rem // Process all files in a directory:
        for %%B in ("%~1\*.*") do (
            call :PROCESS "%%~B"
        )
    ) else (
        rem // Process all files in a directory recursively:
        for /R "%~1" %%B in ("*.*") do (
            call :PROCESS "%%~B"
        )
    )
)
exit /B

:PROCESS
rem // Process a single file:
set /A "COUNTER+=1"
if %COUNTER% EQU 1 (
    >  "%LOCATION%" echo file%COUNTER%=%~nx1
) else (
    >> "%LOCATION%" echo file%COUNTER%=%~nx1
)
exit /B
```

Comment: Thanks!
This solve my problem perfectly, and your comments and explanations helps me learning and understanding.

Answer (score 2):

This Batch file do what you want:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "list=%*"
for %%a in (%1) do set "attr=%%~Aa" & set "dir=%%~DPa"
if "%attr:~0,1%" equ "d" set "list=*.*" & set "dir=%1"
cd "%dir%"
set "i=0"
(for %%a in (%list%) do (
   set /A i+=1
   echo file!i!=%%~NXa
)) > aFile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

floop1.bat runs floop2.bat for each instance of a (*.ext) file in a directory.

floop1.bat:

```
for %%f in (*.ext) do @call floop2.bat "%%f"
```

floop2.bat:

```
@echo %1
```

Answer (score 0):

Save this script as *test.bat*, open *Cmd Prompt* from its folder, and run your batch with the target folder path as a parameter. It will save names of all files stored in the target folder to *files.txt*.

```
@echo off
set "dir=%~1"
pushd "%dir%"
For /R "%dir%" %%G IN (*.*) do (
 echo %%G >> files.txt )
popd
exit /b

c:\\batches\test.bat "K:\Files"
```

You can add the above command to your batch *desktop shortcut's* *Properties - Target* field, so next time you doubleclick the shortcut, the batch will run. However, I doubt that drag-n-drop operations are supported by Cmd.exe. :)